# Possible to represent NaN in scientific notation?

Tags: sql, floating-point, nan

Is there a way to represent `NaN` in SQL with some sort of 'special value' ? Or is it always necessary to use a cast from a string to represent it, for example:

```
SELECT CAST('NaN' AS FLOAT)
-- NaN
```

Is there any such value-construction I can use directly, such as:

```
SELECT 1.2345e-6789
-- NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `0.0/0.0`: IEEE 754 requires that the division of zero by zero to result in `NaN`.

Comment: although a lot of times the database will raise an error if you try division by 0, before returning `NaN`.